# Passing a whole Windows application (GUI at least) to another Windows user

Tags: windows, multiple-users

I have a client who would like to be able to run a program across multiple users on their system. This program can have only one of it open on a machine at a time, and every user (~5) has their own unique login. Additionally, this program is critical *and* it takes a few minutes to shut down and to start back up.

Is there a way to run a program in such a way that any user can access it, or pass the GUI to users?

We have it run as a service through session 0 currently, but they want direct control and Windows is making that more and more difficult.

EDIT: I do not have access to the source code for this program; I am merely the technician who works on the system.

The application uses specific ports to talk to field devices, and trying to open a second instance is not allowed as it cannot bind to the port.

There is a way to run it as a service, and they have a web interface that can be used, agnostic of the user, but the software has certain actions that cannot be performed on the website.

Finally, yes, it is on a shared workstation with multiple users.

Since I cannot actually change the software, I was hoping for an outside solution, but I don't think that's going to be possible.

Comment: Can you clarify. Do they want only a single instance of this program to run among several users on different computers? Or they want to run a single instance of this program on a computer shared my multiple users simultaneously?  Introducing a "license server" concept might make sense.  Are they looking to change the product's source code to accommodate this? Or are they looking for some sort of external solution? Finally, is the reason to run the program "one at a time" for a technical reason (if so, then what?). Or is it strictly about controlling licenses?

Comment: Using *two* programs, a service and a GUI app that talk to each other through a named pipe is the common approach.

Answer (score 0):

A window is tied to its desktop (and therefore its windowstation and session) and cannot be moved to another session.

The sane approach would be a global mutex and just force a single instance. Optionally a way to kill any an instance when a new user logs in and wants to take over.

Otherwise you should rewrite the program so that the main part (database, hardware access or whatever you are doing) is in a service in session 0 and users just runs a GUI application that connects to the service with a named pipe or some other form of IPC.